# Getting rotation information from Content:// and File:// URIs

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image

I am having problems getting a users' pick of an image and then determining if rotating it is necessary. I thought I would be clever and make all my processing operate on Uris, so as to be agnostic of exactly where the images came from, but the methods I have seen for determining rotation seem to require Exif information that doesn't work on Content:// type of Uri.

**Question:** How can I determine if an image needs rotation if my handle to it is a Uri, and you do not know for sure where that image came from?

I am doing this to get an image:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,
               android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_IMAGE_LOAD);
```

... and in onActivityResult() I am receiving the Uri for later processing.

```
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        // if the imageUri needs rotation, then fix it here (I know how to fix it).
        // ... but I think I need to use Exif data which I can't get from Content:// URI
        // hmmmmmmmm


        doMyProcessingOnUri(context, imageUri);
```

Apparently Android 7.0 has changed some aspects of using Intents like this, and I am thinking that much of the posted help on this relates to pre-7.0.

Comment: My processing ideally would be able to handle bitmaps that came from Gallery, Camera (eventually), or even my own project resources such as Drawables and Asset/ or Raw/. As far as I can tell, all of these can be made into Bitmaps and all can be represented as Uri - that is why Uri seems like a good common-denominator for manipulating images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [Introducing the ExifInterface Support Library](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html):

> For apps that receive images from other apps with a content:// URI (such as those sent by apps that target API 24 or higher), ExifInterface now works directly off of an InputStream; this allows you to easily extract Exif information directly out of content:// URIs you receive without having to create a temporary file.

They go on to show exactly how to extract rotation information:

```
InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(in);
int rotation = 0;
int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(
    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
switch (orientation) {
  case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
    rotation = 90;
    break;
  case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
    rotation = 180;
    break;
  case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
    rotation = 270;
    break;
}
```

You can include the ExifInterface Support Library by using the following Gradle import:

```
compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.1"
```

Comment: Wow. This looks encouraging and I did not see this before now. Thanks I will check it out.

Comment: Is Ok in emulator? this return 0 always in emulator android.